# Change the href of the google +1 button using jquery

Tags: jquery, href, google-plus

how can I change the href attribute of my google +1 button via some jQuery

The button initially loads with an empty href.

here is what I have tried so far

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var qrCode = 'A12345';
    var shareLink = "http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>/show.php?qrCode="+qrCode;
    $("#shareLink").attr("href", shareLink);
});

<g:plusone size='medium' id='shareLink' annotation='none' href='' callback='countGoogleShares'></g:plusone>
```

Comment: i have tried giving the plusone button an id or a class and changing it on document.ready with the following.  $("#shareLink").attr("href", shareLink);

Comment: @peledies please update your original post to reflect what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work the way I wanted it to.  I restructured the code a bit to get it to work.  Instead of trying to change out the href attribute on document.ready, I ended up creating an empty div to be the container for the google plus button and writing the button with the correct href via .html()

```
//load the google plus javascript api
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
    {"parsetags": "explicit"}
</script>

//create an empty div to be the target of the google plus button
<div id="plusContent"></div>

<script>
    //get the qrcode to append to the url (ajax call in real life)
    var qrCode = 'A12345';

    //build the google plus object text string
    var googleShareLink = "<g:plusone size='medium' id='shareLink' class='shareLink'  annotation='none' href='http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>/show.php?qrCode="+qrCode+"' callback='countGoogleShares'></g:plusone>";

    //write the google plus object to the target div
    $("#plusContent").html(googleShareLink);

    //render the +1 buttons in the target location
    gapi.plusone.go("plusContent");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the JSAPI to [explicitly render](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#example-explicit-render) the +1 button within the jQuery function after  you set the href.

Answer (score 0):

Select the tag using jquery's ".next()" function.  You just need to put a selectable tag just before this button.

Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need to have the HTML in a JS string.

I created [a page](http://www.adamkoch.com/) similar where I created a div and inside of it I put my g:plusone tag. I put the URL as an attribute in the div as "data-url", but you wouldn't have to do that here.

```
<div class="plusoneContent" data-url="http://www.adamkoch.com/2012/05/04/moz-proxy-issues/">
<g:plusone></g:plusone>
</div>
```

Then I am calling gapi.plusone.render and passing in the URL:

```
var url = $(this).data('url');
gapi.plusone.render(this, {href: url});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code which works correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
</script>
<div id="plusone-div" class="plusone"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    gapi.plusone.render('plusone-div',{"size": "medium", "count": "true", "href": "[http://MySite.Com/]"});
</script>
```